# How to let user have an option to disable splash screen

Tags: java

Currently, I am showing splash screen in my desktop application using the following way

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_12-b04 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: org.yccheok.jstock.gui.MainFrame
SplashScreen-Image: images/splash/jstock2-wording.png
Class-Path: lib/library.lib
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

However, some users request to disable the splash screen during startup.

I know I can achieve this, by not using facility provided by Manifest file.

Instead, I write my own custom Java code.

**To read a config file, and decide whether to spawn a thread to show a splash screen before the main application launching.**

However, I still prefer to use the facility provided by Manifest instead of writing my own code.

Is there any way I can disable the splash screen, if user wish to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution would be to provide the user with a version of the JAR that didn't have the splash-screen-image manifest entry.

The only other option is to write a wrapper script or native code launcher for your app, and have that run the java command using the "-splash" option ... or not ... depending on a script argument, environment variable or preference file.

According to the [javadoc](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html), it is only possible to use the native splash screen via the command line option or the JAR file manifest entry.  So if you want some clever / user friendly way to turn the splash screen on/off via a user preference file, your custom launcher has to read the preference file and do what needs to be done **before** you launch the JVM.

Comment: When user first time launch the application, splash screen will *always* shown. Only later, user can choose to disable splash screen in next launching.

Comment: Create two batch files, one with `-splash` command argument and another without and let enduser decide which to invoke. That's really the best you can get.